# glob syntax working not as expected( [ ] *)

Tags: python, glob

I have a folder containing 4 files.

- Keras_entity_20210223-2138.h5
- intent_tokens.pickle
- word_entity_set_20210223-2138.pickle
- LSTM_history.h5

I used code:

```
NER_MODEL_FILEPATH = glob.glob("model/[Keras_entity]*.h5")[0]
```

It's working correctly since NER_MODEL_FILEPATH is a list only containing the path of that Keras_entity file. Not picking that other .h5 file.

But when I use this code:

```
WORD_ENTITY_SET_FILEPATH = glob.glob("model/[word_entity_set]*.pickle")[0]
```

It's not working as expected, rather than picking up only that word_entity_set file,
this list contains both of those two pickle files.
Why would this happen?

Comment: Hint: what do square brackets do? Look at [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html#index-2)

Comment: Why did you even *put* those brackets there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply remove the square brackets: `word_entity_set*.pickle`

Per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html#index-2):

> `[seq]` matches any character in *seq*

So `word_entity_set_20210223-2138.pickle` is matched because it starts with a `w`, and `intent_tokens.pickle` is matched because it starts with an `i`.

To be clear, it is working as expected. Your expectations were incorrect.

Comment: I'm still confused about the [Keras_entity]*.h5 part though. If it's matching any one of the characters in <phrase>, There is a 's' in 'Keras' and there is a 's' in 'LSTM_history' as well. Shouldn't that picking up the LSTM_history too? But it's not picking that up.

Comment: @Lykosz: There's an `s` in `LSTM_history`, but the character class would need to match the `L`, not the `s`.

Comment: @Lykosz There's no wildcard at the start, so it'll match only the first character in the basename.

Answer (score 0):

Your code selects intent_tokens.pickle and word_entity_set_20210223-2138.pickle because your glob is incorrect. Change the glob to `"word_entity_set*.pickle"`

When you use `[<phrase>]*.pickle`, you're telling the globber to match one of any of the characters in `<phrase>` plus any characters, plus `".pickle"`. So "wordwordword.pickle" will match, so will:

- wwww.pickle
- .pickle
- ***w***.pickle

But

- xw.pickle
- foobar.pickle

will not.

There are truly infinite permutations.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I don't think the `*` works that way.

Comment: Create a file with name "wordwordword.pickle" in the directory. This demonstrates that `[]*` works this way.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html

Comment: @user2357112 Yeah, they're thinking of regex. It actually means any **one** of the characters in `<phrase>`, followed by anything (`*`), followed by `.pickle`.

Comment: @wjandrea, correct. A more succinct way for me to put it would have been: `[word_entity_set]*.pickle` is equivalent to `[word_entiys]*.pickle`. Changing the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Maybe an example would help. `wx.pickle` matches the glob even though `x` isn't in the character set. By your interpretation, it shouldn't match.

Comment: @Michael I think you misunderstood. I'm saying `*` doesn't work how you think. In a glob, `*` is a wildcard character that means "anything", not a modifier like in regex that means "zero or more of the preceding".

Comment: `intent_tokens.pickle` matches even though the character set doesn't have `k` in it, too.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica, "wx.pickle" does not match `glob.glob("word_entity_set*.pickle")`. Have I misunderstood your critique?

Comment: @wjandrea, I think that you may not understand how `*` works in `glob.glob`
```
>>> print(os.listdir("./")
... )
['word_entity_set_foo.pickle', 'LSTM_history.h5', 'wx.pickle', 'intent_tokens.pickle', 'word_entity_set_20210223-2138.pickle', 'wordwordword.pickle', 'Keras_entity_20210223-2138.h5']
>>> glob.glob("[word_entity_set]*.pickle")
['word_entity_set_foo.pickle', 'wx.pickle', 'intent_tokens.pickle', 'word_entity_set_20210223-2138.pickle', 'wordwordword.pickle']
>>> glob.glob("word_entity_set*.pickle")
['word_entity_set_foo.pickle', 'word_entity_set_20210223-2138.pickle']
```

Comment: `wx.pickle` matches `[word_entity_set]*.pickle`, not `word_entity_set*.pickle`.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica, but the OP doesn't want to match "wx.pickle"

Is this not obvious from the accepted answer?

Comment: I'm not saying that they want to match `wx.pickle`. I'm saying that if your answer were correct, the original glob *wouldn't* match `wx.pickle`, but if you test it, it does match. It's a test case showing your answer is (still) wrong.

Comment: @Michael I was able to read it, but I really don't understand what you're trying to say. For example, `x` is not a member of the character set `[word_entiys]`.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica, it does not, is this not clear?

`>>> os.listdir()
['word_entity_set_foo.pickle', 'LSTM_history.h5', 'wx.pickle', 'intent_tokens.pickle', 'word_entity_set_20210223-2138.pickle', 'wordwordword.pickle', 'Keras_entity_20210223-2138.h5']
>>> glob.glob("word_entity_set*.pickle")
['word_entity_set_foo.pickle', 'word_entity_set_20210223-2138.pickle']
`
Note the lack of a "wx.pickle" file in the output.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica, I'm also not trying to say that "[word_entiys]" is the correct glob. I'm saying that "word_entity_set*.pickle" is the correct glob.

Comment: @MichaelRuth: `wx.pickle` didn't show up in your output because you didn't test the original glob. You tested the version without the character class. The point we're trying to make here is that your answer is wrong about how `*` interacts with the character class.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica, I see. Any filename that starts with w, o, r, d, _, e, n,t, i, y, or s, and ends with .pickle should pass. But, a filename that starts with "Z" will not match though it should given my explanation. Thank you.